# ASP.Net validate password with salted hash

Tags: asp.net, validation, hash, salt, password-encryption

So I have been following these guidelines on how to hash a password. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing

I was able to hash the password with a salt I stored the salt in a database and I am retrieving the salt from the database just fine.  Where I am getting tripped up is; if I understand this correctly if you hashed a password without a salt it would come out the same, if you use the same salt(from database) with a hash it should validate, and it comes out with a different hashed password.

**Question:**
Why can't I get the same password when using the salt stored in the database?

**Code:**
The code is trying to validate the password using the salt stored in the database. But I get two different passwords.

```
string password = txtSignPass.Text;
        string email = txtSignEmail.Text;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = @email;", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            byte[] salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dr["salt"].ToString());
            string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
                password: password,
                salt: salt,
                prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
                iterationCount: 10000,
                numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
```

Comment: So, what is the question ?

Comment: "if you hashed a password without a salt it would come out the same" the same as what?  The same as if you hash it _with_ a salt?  No.  Otherwise what is the point of salting?

Comment: @Stormcloak sorry I revised the question

Comment: @nurdyguy If you just hashed the password you should get the same value back every time you hashed the same password. But when you add a salt value it changes it entirely and there never could be the same hashed password when using a salt. Right?!? I was just trying to clarify if this is how it is or not so I am understanding it correctly.  Thanks

Comment: You should [avoid using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). And you need to handle your [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) objects like SqlConnection correctly. It should ideally be wrapped in a using statement.. And finally, if you're going to be executing raw queries and commands on the database, I recommend [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) which cleans up the code quite a bit.

Comment: @WilliamRongholt If you hash x then that thing will always get the same result, yes.  So if you hash just the password then that will always match hashing just the password.  If you hash password+salt then that will always match password+salt.  But hashing password will not match hashing password+salt.  Your original statement was a bit confusing and this is what I was trying to clarify.

Comment: @mason thank you I was going to put it in its own class and functions but I was first trying to get it to work before I did that.  I do remember somewhere where they were suggesting just to use Add so thank you for sharing that with me. I'll also look into the Dapper.  My variable salt is getting the right value but hashed is coming up with a different value and I don't know why.

Comment: I implemented my [own working password hasher](https://github.com/mason-mcglothlin/masonogcrm/blob/master/src/DataAccess.Common/PasswordHasher.cs). Well, I borrowed some code from elsewhere, but I integrated it with a demo application you can obtain and spin up with very little effort to play with.

Comment: @mason Thank you I'll try it out

Comment: @mason Thanks again this works wonders!  Just one question since the password hash includes the salt is this actually secure?

Comment: @WilliamRongholt Yes, so long as you don't give the salt out. See [How to store salt?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17421)